# Why is vcard:Email class deprecated?

Tags: owl, ontology, vcf-vcard

Where can I find the thinking behind the decision of making `vcard:Email` class deprecated in the 2006 version of the ontology?

I've googled it, but could not find anything (maybe wrong search terms?). Neither in [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-vcard-rdf-20130502/#d4e1494) nor in [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/vcard-rdf/#d4e1588) document the deprecation is mentioned at all.

What should be used instead?

Should vcard be used or are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why it is deprecated as a concept, but you could use the property `<vcard:hasEmail rdf:resource="mailto:corky@example.com"/>` (http://www.w3.org/TR/vcard-rdf/#Mapping). An alternative might be FOAF if it suits your purpose better. The code then would be `<foaf:mbox rdf:resource="mailto:corky@example.com"/>` (http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_mbox).
But be aware, that this is an Inverse Functional Property and therefore a `foaf:mbox` can never be assigned to another subject, unless this subject is the same subject as before (e.g. name changing after a marriage which may lead to a new FOAF instance for a person (`owl:sameAs`).